# Slice string by character and not index

Tags: python, string, split

I want to create variable from a long string to a small string.

e.g `abcde!mdamdskm` to `abcde`.

I know only what is the special character and not the index.

Answer (score 18):

For getting only first word use index after splitting.

```
a="abcde!mdamdskm"
print a.split("!")[0]
```

Comment: `split()`, not `slice()`! Thank you! btw fyi `partition()` will keep separator in the results

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> "abcde!mdamdskm".split("!")
['abcde', 'mdamdskm']
```

This might not work if you have multiple instances of the special character:

```
>>> "abcde!mdam!dskm".split("!")
['abcde', 'mdam', 'dskm']
```

But you could fix that like this:

```
>>> "abcde!mdam!dskm".split("!", 1)
['abcde', 'mdam!dskm']
```

Comment: and how can I get only the first index to a variable?

Comment: @ariel: `mylist[0]` gives the first element in `mylist`